# How to match cross-field bean validation errors to a single h:message?

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

We're currently building a web application based on JSF and PrimeFaces and want to use Bean Validation to validate the domain model. The problem we currently face is that we want most error messages displayed next to a single input field. For example, suppose there's a constraint "enddate > startdate", implemented as a class-level bean validator, we still want constraint violations for that rule to show up in a h:message/p:message specific to the enddate field rather than in the globalOnly section. Can this be achieved? If so, how?

Comment: Where's your code? Your question is not clear; nothing stops you from adding a `<p:message/>` and use the `for` attribute to specify the target component.

Comment: That'll only work for field level constraints. I'm trying to find out if it's possible to display class-level constraints next to a specific field.